# Running a C++ program with cmd

Tags: c++, command-line, cmd

When I run a program through command line, once the program ends, cmd instantly closes, so I can't see the output easily. Is there anyway to stop this from happening so I can actually verify the output?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Exercises {
public: 
    void sayHello(int x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            cout << "Hello!!" << endl;
    }
}exercise;

int main() {
    exercise.sayHello(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's closing the window when it's run through the command line, we need code to see what's explicitly closing it.

Comment: edited the code in. I tried removing `return 0;` but that didn't work

Comment: @Jueecy, An object declaration.

Comment: system("pause"); or getch() will do it. If you run it through the cmd line, you just get the prompt back - your program's output stays on the screen. I suspect that you mean "when I run it from within my IDE" that the program's output window closes. Look in your IDE for an option to automatically close the output window. - Also, please copy/paste code in the future. Your code above wouldn't compile. I.e loook at pluralization/capitalization of 'exercise'.

Comment: @abaratham, Nothing in here would close the window. By "run through command line", I would expect you to mean you open up a terminal and type `./exercise.exe` or whatever variant.

Comment: @chris, totally forgot about it :P

Comment: The standard way for this is a combination of `cin.ignore` and `cin.get`.

Comment: @enhzflep *Please*, don't recommend the use of `system("pause")`. It's not only platform specific (the system may not have a `pause` command, and if it does, it may do *weird* things, such as pausing the cooling system of a nuclear reactor) but it's also **not** the *right* way to do this. For more, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong

Comment: @enhzflep in response to "your code above wouldn't compile": please make sure you know what you are talking about before you try to correct someone like that. But thanks for your advice, although, i'm not using an IDE, I'm using Sublime Text to build my code, then running the file that is created in my project folder.

Comment: @enhzflep and the code, as shown, works fine. `Exercises` is the name of the class and `exercise` is the name of a variable, associated with an instance of the class.

Comment: and @chris your suggestion of cin.ignore seems to have helped get rid of the symptom, but I have a feeling there is a better way of doing it/ I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @abaratham, As far as standard, guaranteed behaviours go, that combination is the best I know of. You have to adjust it based on what's left in the input buffer in order to not have it just skip over or wait for two enter presses, though.

Comment: In Visual studio, you can press ctrl+f5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use cin.get();

It will wait for you to press enter or until you close the program.

Answer (score 2):

Following methods can help in keeping the command window till another input is provided.

```
#include <conio.h>
void main(){

// your program here

 getch();
}
```

Another way is to use 
    `system("pause");` at the end of your program.

Comment: when i use getch() it won't compile, not sure if i'm doing something wrong

Comment: You need to include `conio.h`, which I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Try using `getchar()` instead of `getch()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pause the execution of the program for a certain amount of time with:

```
sleep(5); // sleep for 5 seconds
```

You could place that at the end of the program before `return 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind waiting for a keypress at the end of your program, you could put something in.

The simplest way in Windows is to do:

```
system("pause");
```

Don't do this if you are releasing your software though.  You can implement the behaviour of the `pause` command easily enough.

```
std::cout << "Press any key to continue . . . " << std::flush;
while( !_kbhit() ) Sleep(25);
getch();
```

That's using stuff from `conio.h`.

However, I'm concerned about the `cmd` shell itself closing.  When you say you "run with cmd", are you actually running up a shell, then typing in your program name and hitting Enter?  If that closes the shell, then something is wrong.  More likely, you're running it by double-clicking the file in Explorer, right?

Comment: Yes I am double clicking the file in explorer